# WebDAV versioning problems during upload

Tags: 2010, webdav

We experienced an issue where users were uploading files using Windows Explorer (WebDAV).  While uploading large files, it would continuously create new versions.  A 10 MB file ended up with 268 different versions.  This was quickly overwhelming SharePoint storage.

What is the recommended configuration in SharePoint to avoid this issue?

Comment: What IE version you are using? are you uploading multiple time? any workflow enable on the library?

Comment: This runaway versioning happens when they upload a single file a single time through Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer).  No workflow on the library.